# sliding window technique for multiple people detection

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, sliding-window

I am working on video surveillance application for detecting people. Currently I am implementing HOG descriptor as the detector. However, I have a problem regarding the sliding window technique. My code is only able to detect single person. I am using also Group Rectangles from MexOpen CV to creat multiple bounding boxes. Anybody has idea how to write sliding window technique to detect multiple object? Thank you.

```
      % Reading the image
      im = strcat ('C:\Users\Documents\MATLAB\HOG\HOG\images\16.bmp');
      im = imread (im);

      win_size= [64, 128];

      [lastRightCol lastRightRow d] = size(im);

      counter = 1;
      %% Scan the window by using sliding window object detection

      % this for loop scan the entire image and extract features for each sliding window
      % Loop on scales (based on size of the window)
      for s=1:0.5:3
          disp(strcat('s is',num2str(s)));
          X=win_size(1)*s;
          Y=win_size(2)*s;
          for y = 1:X/4:lastRightCol-Y
              for x = 1:Y/4:lastRightRow-X
                  p1 = [x,y];
                  p2 = [x+(X-1), y+(Y-1)];
                  po = [p1; p2] ;

                  % Croped image and scan it.
                  crop_px = [po(1,1) po(2,1)];
                  crop_py  = [po(1,2) po(2,2)];

                  topLeftRow = ceil(min(crop_px));
                  topLeftCol = ceil(min(crop_py));

                  bottomRightRow = ceil(max(crop_px));
                  bottomRightCol = ceil(max(crop_py));

                  cropedImage = img(topLeftCol:bottomRightCol,topLeftRow:bottomRightRow,:);

                  % Get the feature vector from croped image using HOG descriptor
                  featureVector{counter} = getHOGDescriptor(img);
                  boxPoint{counter} = [x,y,X,Y];
                  count = counter+1;
                  x = x+2;
               end
            end
         end

         label = ones(length(featureVector),1);
         P = cell2mat(featureVector);

         % each row of P' correspond to a window
         % classifying each window
         [~, predictions] = svmclassify(P', label,model); 


         % set the threshold for getting multiple detection
         % the threshold value is 0.7
         get_detect = predictions.*[predictions>0.6];

         % the the value after sorted
         [r,c,v]= find(get_detect);


         %% Creating the bounding box for detection 
         for ix=1:length(r)
             rects{ix}= boxPoint{r(ix)};
         end

         if (isempty(rects))
             rects2=[];
         else
             rects2 = cv.groupRectangles(rects,3,'EPS',0.35);
         end



         for i = 1:numel(rects2)
             rectangle('Position',[rects2{i}(1),rects2{i}(2),64,128], 'LineWidth',2,'EdgeColor','y');
         end

     end
```

Comment: Could you create an mcve, please. see this for help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: oo sorry I forget to attach my code. Here I have attached the code above. @kkuilla, hopefully you can help me. thank you

Comment: Where are the test images? You should also add the `computer-vision` tag. You use the function `getHOGDescriptor().`You haven't mention which one you are using. There are a at least two you can download.

Comment: @kkuilla. I cannot write all my code here. It will be very long. I just want to know whether my sliding window technique is correct or not to detect multiple people inside the frames. The function `getHOGDescriptor()`, i modified from someone code that published here : [HOG code for Matlab](http://chrisjmccormick.wordpress.com/2013/05/09/hog-descriptor-in-matlab/). and I am using Group Rectangles from mex opencv to create multiple bounding box. But, the main issue is still on sliding window detection. hopefully you can help me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Computer Vision System Toolbox includes `vision.PeopleDetector` object which uses a sliding window HoG-SVM algorithm.

Comment: thank for your advice. However, for my project, I am not allowed to use any MATLAB toolboxes. I have to build my own code. Therefore, here i found any difficulties on making sliding window detection for multiple people detection. @Dima

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are testing the model correctly. [Here](http://thebrainiac1.blogspot.com.es/2012/07/v-behaviorurldefaultvmlo.html) you have a complete example, and this is the main code for sliding window:

```
topLeftRow = 1;
topLeftCol = 1;
[bottomRightCol bottomRightRow d] = size(im);

fcount = 1;

% this for loop scan the entire image and extract features for each sliding window
for y = topLeftCol:bottomRightCol-wSize(2)   
    for x = topLeftRow:bottomRightRow-wSize(1)
        p1 = [x,y];
        p2 = [x+(wSize(1)-1), y+(wSize(2)-1)];
        po = [p1; p2];
        img = imcut(po,im);     
        featureVector{fcount} = HOG(double(img));
        boxPoint{fcount} = [x,y];
        fcount = fcount+1;
        x = x+1;
    end
end

lebel = ones(length(featureVector),1);
P = cell2mat(featureVector);
% each row of P' correspond to a window
[~, predictions] = svmclassify(P',lebel,model); % classifying each window

[a, indx]= max(predictions);
```