# HOG descriptor for multiple people detection

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing, matlab-cvst

I am doing a real-time people detection using HOG-LBP descriptor and using a sliding window approach for the detector also LibSVM for the classifier. However, after classifier I never get multiple detected people, sometimes is only 1 or might be none. I guess I have a problem on my classification step. Here is my code on classification:

```
     label = ones(length(featureVector),1);
     P = cell2mat(featureVector);

     % each row of P' correspond to a window
     % classifying each window
     [~, predictions] = svmclassify(P', label,model); 


     % set the threshold for getting multiple detection
     % the threshold value is 0.7
     get_detect = predictions.*[predictions>0.6];

     % the the value after sorted
     [r,c,v]= find(get_detect);


     %% Creating the bounding box for detection 
     for ix=1:length(r)
         rects{ix}= boxPoint{r(ix)};
     end

     if (isempty(rects))
         rects2=[];
     else
         rects2 = cv.groupRectangles(rects,3,'EPS',0.35);
     end



     for i = 1:numel(rects2)
         rectangle('Position',[rects2{i}(1),rects2{i}(2),64,128], 'LineWidth',2,'EdgeColor','y');
     end
```

For the whole my code, I have posted here : [HOG with SVM] ([sliding window technique for multiple people detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235748/sliding-window-technique-for-multiple-people-detection))

I really need a help for it. Thx.

Comment: What is the output of the 'predictions' array? If all values are 0, then the problem is in the classifier itself (maybe bad training, or bad descriptor extraction).

Comment: The output is the gradient feature values from the descriptor after being classified with the training images in the `model`. Even until I set the `threshold`, the output of predictions are still in features values not 0. The one that I might confused is only the bounding box, I guess my method to create the bounding box is not correct. Because it doesnt show me any detected people. Could you help me how to set bounding box from classied data? Thx. @phyrox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have problems wiith the sliding window, you can use [this](http://thebrainiac1.blogspot.com.es/2012/07/v-behaviorurldefaultvmlo.html) code:

```
topLeftRow = 1;
topLeftCol = 1;
[bottomRightCol bottomRightRow d] = size(im);

fcount = 1;

% this for loop scan the entire image and extract features for each sliding window
for y = topLeftCol:bottomRightCol-wSize(2)   
    for x = topLeftRow:bottomRightRow-wSize(1)
        p1 = [x,y];
        p2 = [x+(wSize(1)-1), y+(wSize(2)-1)];
        po = [p1; p2];
        img = imcut(po,im);     
        featureVector{fcount} = HOG(double(img));
        boxPoint{fcount} = [x,y];
        fcount = fcount+1;
        x = x+1;
    end
end

lebel = ones(length(featureVector),1);
P = cell2mat(featureVector);
% each row of P' correspond to a window
[~, predictions] = svmclassify(P',lebel,model); % classifying each window

[a, indx]= max(predictions);
```

Comment: thank you for your advice. I have noticed that my problem is not on sliding window. My sliding window has no problem. The only thing my problem is the value after classification. How do I can create a multiple bounding box for multiple detected people based on classification value? Based on my code above, I sometimes only get one detected people or even none. @phyrox

Comment: The code above that you gave me, it only gives a single bounding box for a single detected person. How do I create multiple bounding box for multiple detected person?. @phyrox

Comment: In the code above, I use `max`to select only one window. Instead, you can use a threshold: `predictions>0.5`. For these indexes you should access to the corresponding window. To access it, you should store `po` on a cell like `boxPoint`

Comment: I have used `threshold` to filter the value. If you notice on my code above I set, `get_predict=predictions.*[predictions>0,6]`. Set 0 for value below than `threshold` and keep the value which is greater than 0.6. Afterwards, I sorted the value by using `[r,c,v] = find (get_detect)`. The value after sorted will be used to determine bounding boxes. Here I am using mexopencv `cv.groupRectangles` for create the bounding boxes and showed me poor results on detection. If you have any good way for my code, I really appreaciate. Thx @phyrox