# How to implement HOG-LBP for Real-Time application?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, detection

I am using HOG-LBP to detect people in crowd. However, I have a problem on how to implement this method to work in real-time. So far, my program is not working in real-time and taking time to process (since it needs to scan the whole image before it detects people in an image).  I have posted also small part of my code here: [HOG-LBP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235748/sliding-window-technique-for-multiple-people-detection), but here my program cant work in real-time application. Any suggestion how to implement HOG-LBP for Real-Time application? Thank you.

Comment: Can you use GPU version of opencv HOG? From my exxperience, it gives a significant speedup.

Comment: it would be easy for me, but i am not allowed to use any toolbox for my research..  I have tried many ways, but still takes time because the sliding window detection needs to scan whole image.. do you have any suggestion how to implement HOG for real-time? thx.. @marol

Comment: I don't know if you undersootd me correctly, I meant in opencv it is already implemented a GPU version of HOG detection - take a look here:  http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html.

Comment: I did exactly understand you. But here for my research, I am not allowed to use such kind of GPU or built-in toolbox as in MATLAB. I have to scratch as conventional my code. Now, my problem is only how to implement for real-time my code. If you have any idea or suggestion, I really appreciate it. Thx.. @marol

Answer (score -1):

You can try scaling your image down.

This way you can speed up your detection, possibly.

However, the trade off will be that the accuracy might suffer.

Worth a try anyway.

Comment: I have scaled down the image,, but still take time.. since i am using sliding window detection to detect people in an image.. here is my link for my sliding window detection, perhaps you can help me to find out the solution.. [HOG-LBP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235748/sliding-window-technique-for-multiple-people-detection) thx @TheBlueNotebook