# Using hog implementation of opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to use hog implementation of opencv in order to detect bodies in images. I found in opencv's folder samples peopledetect.cpp which are a default implementation of the hog algorithm using a pretrained model. With a little googling I found that this default approach isn't working satisfactorily. I have to create my own model using libSvm. My first question is there any tutorial or example that explains this procedure? Second one, what my model suppose to learn? What are going to be me training samples? Images that contains only people?

Edit Question: Is there a chance to train an one-class model, containing only images with people bodies? I am trying to understand the code [in here](https://github.com/DaHoC/trainHOG). It calculates the hog features for a database and train a svm model. In evaluation process it uses the hog cascade with detectMultiScale. What is the relation of detectMultiScale with SVM?

I have train a libsvm with linear kernel with images provided [from here](http://www.emt.tugraz.at/~pinz/data/GRAZ_01/). Images are of two kinds one that containing persons and one without persons. The train result was near to 98%(wuth svm_predict). How can I locate the position of a body inside a test image? Can I use detectmultiscale for that purpose? Feed multiscadlefunction with svm model? I have noticed in my svm model that some support vectors beggining without the label in the beggining of the line but only with the sign. Is this something normal, or it could be a bug?

Hogcascade it seems that it doesn't work for me(f.e in the [image](http://media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/cb/38/9c/cb389c630a739a880796b25392f7463e.jpg)):

```
CascadeClassifier body_cascade;
body_cascade.load("cascades/hogcascade_pedestrians.xml");    
Mat image, gray_image;
image = imread( fileName, 1 );
resize(image, image, Size(150, 200));

vector<Rect> bodies;
cvtColor(image, gray_image, CV_BGR2GRAY);
body_cascade.detectMultiScale( gray_image, bodies, 1.3, 5 );
cout << "size of detection" << bodies.size() << endl;
```

Every time I am getting 0 bodies.

Comment: note, that apart from the svm solution, you also could train a CascadeClassifier with HOG features for [persons](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data/hogcascades).

Comment: Cool, I will check it out! DetectmultiScale works only with cascade models?

Comment: i think so. (were you asking, if you can get rects from the svmdetector ?)

Comment: I think this work can help you: http://www.geocities.ws/talh_davidc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Take a bunch of images containing people. You need all people marked with a rectangle around them.
2. Convert these ROIs to HOG features (these will be positive training data). Also convert non-people areas of images to HOG features (negative training data). The HOG features need to be all of the same dimension. Have a look in the respective papers for the optimal parameters i.e. how many HOG cells per rectangle, dimensionality per HOG cell (31 normally). This requires that all rectangles have the same aspect ratio (I think).
3. Train a classifier. Your training data is all the features you computed in the previous step, your labels are +1 for the positive training data (the HOG features referring to people) and -1 for the negative training data. You can pass both of these to libsvm. Again, read the papers to see what parameters they used for training the SVM. I'm guessing it's a linear SVM with potentially an L1 distance measure because HOGs are very much histograms and histograms don't work well with the L2 norm. But that's just a guess.
4. Libsvm will return a model. You should test how good it is by measuring precision/recall on your test data. (Or measure ROC, or whatever you want). Libsvm has a function for this, too.

Comment: I have train a libsvm with linear kernel with images provided from here http://pascallin.ecs.soton.ac.uk/challenges/VOC/. Images are of two kinds one that containing persons and one without persons. The train result was near to 98%(wuth svm_predict). How can I locate the position of a body inside a test image? Can I use detectmultiscale for that purpose? Feed multiscadlefunction with svm model?

Comment: The training result is completely useless to know. That's why you always evaluate on test! For detection you have to evaluate your model/filter on multiple scales. I don't know which functions that are but a sliding window approach at multiple scales with non-maxima suppression works.

Comment: How clean has to be the training set? I mean, my training set, the positive samples are quite noisy. Is this an issue?

Comment: 1) I don't know what you mean by "noisy". Are the images noisy because of high ISO, or are there many false positive training data? 2) how about you just try it out?

Comment: Sorry I mean noisy background (semantic noise). Images with bodies with noisy background.

Comment: That should be fine but read the papers. Try it out, if that turns out to be a problem ask a specific question about this. But try it, we're just guessing. In theory the background should get very low weights from the SVM.

Comment: Yea ok, thanks for the time. Can you at last suggest a paper for the window sliding, or for the whole process?

Comment: Wikipedia: Histogram of Oriented Gradients. The seminal paper for HOG is http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf. Sliding window: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235748 , http://thebrainiac1.blogspot.com.es/2012/07/v-behaviorurldefaultvmlo.html  http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs143/proj4/

Answer (score 2):

1. The procedure is quite straight-forward on paper. Extract HOG features from an image, create a training vector, assign a label and give it to a classifier to learn. [This](https://github.com/DaHoC/trainHOG/wiki/trainHOG-Tutorial) would be an excellent place to experiment. I'm not sure how effective [this](http://chrisjmccormick.wordpress.com/2013/05/09/hog-person-detector-tutorial/) is, but it's definitely a good source. And some wisdom [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/10374/how-to-training-hog-and-use-my-hogdescriptor/) as well.
2. Your model is supposed to learn what the HOG features of an image with a person looks like. One training sample is going to be the HOG feature vector (and not direct image itself). For the negative class, it's again going to be HOG features from images not containing people.